# Getting SCOPE_IDENTITY from SQL Server on Insert

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, dbnull, scope-identity

I guess it is too late and I'm too tired to see what I'm doing wrong. Here is what I'm trying:

```
int imageId = imageDal.AddImage(new SqlParameter[]
        {
            new SqlParameter("@IMAGE_ID", 
        SqlDbType.Int, Int32.MaxValue, ParameterDirection.Output,
        true, 0, 0,"IMAGE_ID", DataRowVersion.Current,DBNull.Value),

        new SqlParameter("@IMAGE", 
        SqlDbType.Image, 11, ParameterDirection.Input,
        true, 0, 0,"IMAGE", DataRowVersion.Current,image)
        });

public int AddImage(SqlParameter[] spParams)
{
    SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(BaseDAL.ConnectionStringImages, INSERT_IMAGE_SQL, spParams);
    return Convert.ToInt32(spParams[0].Value);
}
```

Stored Procedure:

```
[dbo].[sp_insert_image]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @IMAGE_ID int OUT,
    @IMAGE image
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO images
    (IMAGE)
    VALUES
    (@IMAGE)
    SELECT @IMAGE_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
GO
```

I get DBNull as spParams[0].Value. I've tried setting value of @IMAGE_ID to a constant in my stored procedure yet it didn't change anything so the problem isn't with my stored procedure (that is what I think).

When I execute the procedure from sql management studio, I see the inserted_id returning..

Comment: Looking at it, it all looks sane; you've set the direction, for example; I *assume* `INSERT_IMAGE_SQL` is set to `[dbo].[sp_insert_image]`; I wonder if maybe `SqlHelper` is distorting things, but that seems... odd.

Comment: There must be something wrong with it. I'll restart my computer if I can't find a solution :) Yes private static string INSERT_IMAGE_SQL = "sp_insert_image";
Also the procedure runs smoothly, row gets inserted yet I can't get the id of it - in other words, get exception in convert.toint32..

Comment: you cite `sp_insert_image`, not `[dbo].[sp_insert_image]` - is there perhaps another version in your name that is getting called in preference? a `[pabuc].[sp_insert_image]` for example?

Comment: No, actually there is only 1 stored procedure in this database and this is sp_insert_image

Comment: Does the parameters update automatically? I mean do I have to do something extra to set the value of the desired sqlparam? I'm sure it is set in stored proc but I can't get it. I need to find a way of getting that value :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up with executescalar and returning the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` directly from SP.

If there is another way of doing it and getting the value from the sqlparameter, I'd love to hear that out.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, the problem is in **ExecuteNonQuery** method. It returns object array, instead of sqlparam's array.

Just have a ref on the output sqlparam object and get the value from that ref.

Good Luck!

**P.S.** There's another solution. Check the link

http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/dotnet-distributed-apps/160/Data-Access-Application-Block-Output-Parameters

Answer (score 0):

You put Like this....

```
[dbo].[sp_insert_image]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @IMAGE_ID int OUT,
    @IMAGE image
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO images (IMAGE) VALUES (@IMAGE)
    SET @IMAGE_ID  = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
GO
```