# Entity Framework and SCOPE_IDENTITY

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, scope-identity

I have a stored procedure that inserts into a table then executes this line

```
SET @returnVal = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

and after that I've tried both:

```
SELECT @returnVal
```

and

```
return @returnVal
```

When I execute the stored procedure from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, I get the expected result with `SELECT @returnVal` - the identity column for the inserted data is selected.

However when I add the stored procedure to my ADO.Net Entity Data Model / EntityFramework class / .edmx class and execute the stored procedure in my C# code, I get the value -1 returned without fail.

Is it possible to get the value that I want, the new identity value, returned?

I realize that I could manually bind the stored procedure to the insert action of the table in my model - but this is not an option.  There are far too many insert procedures to do this manual work every time I regenerate my model class(es).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting SCOPE\_IDENTITY from SQL Server on Insert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918574/getting-scope-identity-from-sql-server-on-insert)

Comment: Are you using ExecuteNonQuery when you should be using ExecuteScalar?

Comment: and the executing code is ? NonQuery by any chance

Comment: You need to call the sp using executescalar

Comment: I've taken your answer out of the question and added as a wiki answer below. If you want to do this yourself let me know and I will delete the wiki answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare a output type of parameter in your procedure definition:

```
 create procedure [dbo].[Procedurename] @returnVal int output
 as 
 SET @returnVal = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

and while calling the stored procedure call it as:

```
 declare @returnVal int
 exec Procedurename @returnVal output
 print @returnVal
```

Answer (score 0):

`context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` return the command executing result and not the query result.
If you need to get data than use `context.Database.SqlQuery`.

`SET @ReturnVal=SCOPE_IDENTITY()` and then use the select.

Example:
[How to use DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<TElement>(sql, params) with stored procedure? EF Code First CTP5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873607/how-to-use-dbcontext-database-sqlquerytelementsql-params-with-stored-proced)

Comment: This is very likely a good solution, however I marked the other solution as the answer bc it solved my problem and I didn't have to change the way I was calling the stored proc (w EF DbContext) - all I had to do was add an out parameter to the stored procedure and C# code.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>taken from the OPs question</sub>

Adding an output parameter worked (answer marked below).

The stored procedure signature looks like this now:

My stored procedure signature now looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_MyStoreProc ([Multiple Parameters], @returnVal int output)
```

The last line of the stored procedure is:

```
return @returnVal
```

My C# code looks like this now: (db is an instance of my dbContext class)

```
System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter identityParameter = 
new System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter("returnVal", 0);

db.SP_MyStoredProc([Multiple Parameters], identityParameter);

int myNewIdentity = Convert.ToInt32(identityParameter.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you open the edmx file and right click on the function import in the model browser you can tell entity framework that the stored procedure returns a collection of scalars. Then you can essentially call the sproc with mycontext.mysproc().Single() to get the ID.